# error: package does not exist JUnit Command Line - No IDE/Package Managers

Tags: java, junit, command-line

I'm test driving a Hello World Java application from the command line. Running `javac MyTestRunner.java` throws 'error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist' and other similar errors, as well as a couple of 'cannot find symbol' errors.

The errors, as well as my classpath and test files are in the picture attached.

As far as I can tell, this is usually a classpath/junit.jar issue

Since I'm test-driving, the 'HelloWorld' class is not yet working as intended, but should exist.

**HelloWorld**

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        return 0
    }
}
```

[image]

I think this is nearly up and running, but that I'm still missing something important. How can I clear these errors? Are they related, or are there separate issues causing the different types of errors?

Edit: The problem was using multiple tildas instead of '$HOME' in the -cp.

Comment: How are you managing the relevant dependencies? Have you considered using [Maven](https://maven.apache.org) for example?

Comment: Good question, this is a sort of technical exercise so I can't use anything to manage things for me. The idea is that I do it all the first time so that when I move to IntelliJ I know what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: But your project structure seems to be following maven structure. You have different test and main folders. Also, code images are discouraged. Please share code and error log as text in the question.